# Javascript add class to display

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with the javascript code regarding adding text class to result

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: validate,
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        if($('#video_type').val() == '0'){
            $('form').find('.submitBtn').text('Updating...');
            $('form').find('.submitBtn').attr('disabled','');
        }else{
            $('form').find('.card-footer').addClass('d-none');
        }
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal);
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        if($('#video_type').val() == '1') {
            if(percentComplete > 50) {
                percent.addClass('text-white');
            }
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            if(percentComplete == 100) {
                $('.percent').attr('style','top:2px');
                percent.html(`<i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin'>'Processing'</i>`);
            }else{
                percent.html(percentVal);
            }
            bar.width(percentVal);
        }
    },
```

My question is is this the correct way to add this record code:

```
percent.html(`<i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin'>'Processing'</i>`);
```

Comment: Does it work? Then it is good.

Comment: my question is regarding this line, because the color for javascript code it stops on that line and does not read the rest of the script as javascript code

Comment: where the `percent` variable is declared?

Comment: It does it here on the site tough. Can't say much more without more detailed

Comment: i have updated my code
maybe it should be like that? 
percent.html('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin">Processing</i>');